# How can I increment a column in MySQL using Slick 1.0.1

Tags: scala, slick

I am using Slick 1.0.1 with MySQL and would like to increase a numeric column thusly:

```
UPDATE attacks SET counter = counter + 5 WHERE country = 'DE';
```

My Slick class looks like this:

```
object AttackByCountry extends Table[(String, Long)]("attacks") {

def country = column[String]("country", O.primaryKey)
def counter = column[Long]("counter")

def * = country ~ counter
```

I don't know where to begin.  Is it even possible to do in 1.0.1?  Is such incrementing supported in 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Currently not supported in the typesafe API. We have a ticket to add it some time in the future.

https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/497

For now you could use a transaction with a select and subsequent update. Or plain SQL.